# how to pass selected month value from vf page to controller and fetch records for that particular mont

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am using jquery fullcalendar to display records in calendar view. Currently i have a scenario where i am selecting months from vf page and i need to fetch records from controller for the selected month only.

The below javascript is giving me the start date of the month selected.

```
var month = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
var f = month.format('YYYY-MM-01');
```

Ex - if i select `Oct 2016`, it gives as `2016-10-01`

I need to pass this info from vf page to controller and i need to add this in my SOQL filter.

SOQL -

```
eventList = [select Id, Name, Start_Date__c,  End_Date__c   from ABC__c ];
```

In ABC__c object i have startdate & enddate as Date field which can be any date.

How to fit the selected month from vf page to this SOQL .

Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can use `apex:actionfunction` with `apex:param` to pass the value

```
<script>
callactfunc(f);
</script>
```

Then an actionfunction

```
<apex:actionfunction action="{!controllermethod} name="callactfunc" rerender="form">
      <apex:param name="datename" value="" />
</apex:actionfunction>
```

And finally in your controller

```
public void controllermethod(){
string datevar = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('datename');
//... continue with processing

}
```

Comment: Hi Tushar.. Thanks for the help.. But how to design my soql as i have only startdate and enddate .. do i need to create another field..as string datevar will always have start date of every month ..

Comment: @learningmode you can createdynamic SOQl here. like ` WHERE  Start_Date__c <=: stDate  AND End_Date__c   >=: stDate  ]` where `stdate =  date.valueof(datevar)`

Comment: stdate  is a string variable?

Comment: @learningmode nope date type.

Comment: I have wriiten like 'Date stdate = date.valueof(datevar);' i am getting error 'Argument cannot be null'.

Comment: @learningmode check `datevar` is not null. also share your updated code.